# Encrypting/Decrypting Passwords in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am currently encrypting user password and storing them in my DB by using the following code:

```
<cfset encrypted_pass = Hash(#form.pwd#, 'SHA-512')/>
```

Is there a way I can decrypt this password after the fact?

Comment: The `hash()` function is one-way encryption. You cannot decrypt the password, nor should you ever save a password in a way that you _could_ decrypt it.

Comment: ok. I've been reading about the encrypt() and decrypt() built-in function. Is that not normally used for passwords?

Comment: To clarify Adrian's comment and Andrew's answer, from a security standpoint it is better to use a hashing algorithm instead of an encryption algorithm that can be decrypted. That makes it much harder to crack the passwords.

Comment: Agreed with the other posts. Passwords that are encrypted are a bad idea. There is only one person who should _ever_ know a user's password, and that is the user themselves. Encryption and Hashing serve two very different purposes. Check out https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html. Pretty much anything from OWASP is going to be good advice.

Comment: And regarding encrypting passwords, I'm guessing this is so that you can send someone their password in a recovery? Don't do this. Make them reset it instead, and hash the new value. Give them a time-limited, one-time password and make them log in again to change that password. Or something like that. There are tons of things you can do for better security. The OWASP Cheat Sheets go through a lot of options. But nobody should ever be able to recover someone's actual password.

Answer (score 6):

If you are storing passwords in a database, you should always store these as hashes and not using reversible encryption. The method of doing is this "hashing" but not all hashing is created equal and the "hash" function in CFML is not good enough for password hashing.

The reason for using hashing is so if a "bad actor" gains access to your DB they are still not able to obtain your users passwords.

Please see the following article for details and code examples for good password hashing in CFML:

https://www.andrewdixon.co.uk/2020/05/12/password-hashing-in-cfml/

Comment: Understood. I can see why that is best practice.

Comment: @andrewdixon While your answer is 100% correct and your article describes things in more detail, you should still explain in one or two sentences here why hashing should be preferred over a decryptable way to store passwords.

Comment: @SebastianZartner - Originally answer very quickly, now expanded a bit 

Comment: A salt doesn't need to be secret. The main purpose of a salt is to prevent running rainbow tables against your db. It's best to use a unique salt for each user, but it doesn't really matter if anyone has access to your code. A single salt allows someone to build a rainbow table with that salt, but individual salts means that the attacker would have to calculate the hash for each record. That's pretty time-consuming, especially with something like _bcrypt_ or _scrypt_. (NOTE: CF2021 added functions for those: https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords)